# Effective bandwidth for Mars rovers to Earth

Tags: mars, deep-space-network, bandwidth

I'm interested in what the effective bandwidth is for, in particular, the Curiosity and Perseverance rovers back to Earth.

By 'effective' I mean 'averaged over a sufficiently long period', so at least several Sols.  I also mean not just *direct* bandwidth (which I think is relatively tiny compared to the relay bandwitch), but the bandwidth via all the orbiters.  I'd also be interested in knowing if there are systematic medium-term variations due to both Mars/Earth/Sun position and changes in relative orbiter/rover position & timing, but that's less important.  Finally I'm interested in the achieved bandwidth, not a best-case maximum, and I don't care much about the latency (several Sols via a relay is fine, but 'wrote it onto an SD card which a later mission will collect from the surface' is cheating).

This is clearly related to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18475/current-maximum-bandwidth-between-mars-and-earth) but that's asking for the maximum orbiter-to-Earth bandwidth and I'm very much more interested in what the averaged value is in practice.

The best thing I've been able to find is for Curiosity which is [this](https://mars.nasa.gov/msl/mission/communications/#data).  That says up to about 250 Mbits per orbiter pass and I think there are two orbiter passes per Sol (of different orbiters I think).  So that would indicate about 500Mbits or 50MB/Sol for Curiosity, together with some (I think much smaller) direct-to-Earth bandwidth.

Curiosity & Perseverance have the same quoted maximum bandwidth to the relays (2Mbit/s) so I am guessing about the same for Perseverance, but I don't know.

But it would be really interesting to get a more definitive set of figures, hence this question.

Answer (score 3):

From [this article](https://mars.nasa.gov/msl/mission-updates/sols-2159-2162-lots-of-bits/?mu=sols-2159-2162-lots-of-bits), Curiosity has an effective bandwidth of about 60 Megabytes/ sol.

Comment: Oh that's a brilliant pointer.  I'll leave it just in case someone else has other figures, but I think that's the answer.  I'm glad to say it's close to my guess!